# Some questions about OpenLayers

Tags: java, javascript, openlayers

I am researching on OpenLayers to apply this library to my Java web application. I've just worked with it for 2 weeks, and there are some problems that I have not found the solution for them? Could you please spend a little time to help me on below questions:
1. How to send a set of geographical axis of some locations to get the returned positions at the same time?
2. Can I shade a specific country by a given color? How about for a set of adjacent countries?
3. Is there any caching mechanism in OpenLayers that allow us to retrieve the entire map data at the first load, then store it somewhere and reuse it at user's interaction later? If yes, how to store and reuse?
It would be greatly appreciated if you can give me a clue, tutorial or any referenced article related to above questions.
Thank you so much.

Comment: question 1 - please clarify with examples (lat+long).
question 3 - caching of tiles usually isn't useful because it consumes too much space (and bandwidth) and you can never predict what zoom level your user will want at any given point.

Answer (score -2):

There are ton of examples, just have a look at http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/